# Dynamic creation of script tag and src load of it is not working in ie10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I just tried to load the static js file as below

```
function getKey(){ 
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
var scriptEmt =document.createElement('script'); 
scriptEmt.type='text/javascript'; 
scriptEmt.src="https://preview16.abc.com/Svc/js/test.js";
headID.appendChild(scriptEmt);  
calltest();
}
```

Here when i check in network capture - The test.js is successfully loaded. And i can see the js file and its contents in Response body of the URL https://preview16.abc.com/Svc/js/test.js. My test.js file contents looks like this:

```
function calltest(){
alert("I am in test");
}
```

But when i call calltest() in getKey() after headID.appendChild(scriptEmt); statement it says ERROR - SCRIPT5009: 'calltest' is undefined

This happens only in IE10. In IE 9. calltest() function is called successfully and the alert in it comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var fileTag = "<script src='https://preview16.arcot.com/Svc/js/test.js' type='text/javascript' ><\/script>";
document.write(fileTag);
```

Also try

```
var script = document.createElement('script');        
script.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (script.readyState == 'loaded') {
       document.body.appendChild(script);
       calltest();
  }
};
script.src = 'yourscript.js';
```

Comment: I still see the same errror when i do this

 var fileTag = "<script src='https://preview16.abc.com/Svc/js/test.js' type='text/javascript' ><\/script>";
 document.write(fileTag);
 calltest();

As i mentioned earlier, here as well when i check in network capture - The test.js is successfully loaded. And i can see the js file and its contents in Response body of the URL https://preview16.abc.com/Svc/js/test.js. But when i call calltest(); which is in test.js. I get error SCRIPT5009: 'calltest' is undefined

Comment: My actual requirement is as below:

Here i am calling a servlet. Get call happens to the servlet, when document.getElementById('testURL').value + '?opn=getKey&rand='+ Math.random(); is done. This returns the key and a call to the callback() function. In IE 9 this works fine. But in ie 10 it requires some pause after this call. So i had to put the below alerts. Can you help me to know why is this issue in IE10? And how to resolve this? Alerting is a not a right way to do it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: function getKey(){ 
 var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
 var scriptEmt =document.createElement('script'); 
 scriptEmt.type='text/javascript'; 
 scriptEmt.src=document.getElementById('testURL').value + 'opn=getKey&rand='+ Math.random(); 
 if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10.0") != -1){
  alert("alert1..");
  alert("alert2....");
 }
 headID.appendChild(scriptEmt);          
}   

function callback(){ 
...
...
}